# Renamed file not showing in git log

Tags: git, github

I have created a **temp** branch from **main** branch. In the **temp** branch I refactored a file by changing the file name.

So let's say I changed a file with name **A** to name **B** and pushed the commits in branch **B**.

Now if I am doing **git log --name-only origin/master..HEAD** then it is showing **B** as a new file but not showing anything for **A** like removed/deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git commits *never* **rename** a file.  But Git commits never *change* a file either.  Commits just *store* files.

#### But I see changed files all the time

You do.  That's because Git *compares* commits.

Suppose you have commit `a123456`, that contains files `f1.ext` and `f2.ext`.  You check out this commit, and modify the contents of `f2.ext` and run `git add` on it and then `git commit` again, and the new commit has hash ID `789abcd`.

If you check out the old commit again, you'll have `f1.ext` and `f2.ext` with their *old* contents.  If you check out commit `789abcd`, you'll have `f1.ext` and `f2.ext` with their *new* contents.

It's just that the *old* contents of `f1.ext`, in the *older* commit, *match* the *new* contents of `f1.ext` in the *new* commit.  Both commits *contain full copies of both files* (de-duplicated and compressed, in Git's special internal format for files inside commits).

If you *compare* the two commits, though, Git will *notice that `f1.ext` has not changed* and will therefore only *tell you about `f2.ext`*.

Suppose you now delete `f1.ext` entirely, and make a whole new `f3.ext` file that contains the *same data* that *was* in `f1.ext` before, and add the removal of `f1.ext` and the creation of `f3.ext` and commit.  Suppose further that the *new* commit's hash ID is `ef01234`.  We now have *three* commits:

```
   a123456           789abcd            ef01234
f1.ext, f2.ext    f1.ext, f2.ext    f3.ext, f2.ext
```

*Each of the three commits has two files*.  The *names* have changed somewhat in the last commit.  The *contents* of one of the two files changed between the first and middle commit.  But each commit has two files, with two sets of contents.

If we compare `a123456` with `ef01234`, Git will notice that `f2.ext`'s contents have changed (because we changed them once, earlier, then saved the same contents twice).  But it will also notice that `f1.ext`'s *contents* now exist in `ef01234` under the name `f3.ext`.

**If we ask it to do so**, Git will now tell us that between `a123456` and `ef01234`, the way to turn *the former into the latter* includes *renaming* `f1.ext` to `f3.ext`.  This is true even though we didn't rename any files at any time.  That's because Git is not telling us *what we did*, but rather *some set of changes that will achieve the same results*.

#### `git diff`, `git log`, `--name-status`, `--find-renames`, `--follow`, and more

The Git command that compares *any two commits of our choosing* is `git diff`.  This command can take, among many other flags, the following three flags:

```
--name-status
--name-only
--find-renames
```

The first two prevent `git diff` from showing the *change recipe*.  The `--name-only` flag means *present only the names of changed files*.  The `--name-status` flag means *present the names and a status letter*.

The *third* flag tells `git diff` that it *should look for diffs that are simplified by claiming that a file was renamed*.  Using `--no-renames` turns this off, so that instead of a file being `R`enamed (as the status), we will see one file `D`eleted (the old name) and one `A`dded (the new name).  You can tell `git diff` to do this by default, in which case you need the explicit `--no-renames` to disable it.

The `git log` command uses the history in the repository, which consists of nothing more and nothing less than the *commits* in the repository.  Besides storing a *snapshot of every file*, each commit also stores some *metadata*, including things like the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  This committer information lets `git log` show that to you.

One item in the metadata for any commit is the hash ID of this commit's *predecessor* (or *parent*) commit.  That means Git knows which commit comes *before* this commit.

Since a commit holds a snapshot, but also holds the hash ID of the *previous* snapshot, `git log` can obtain *both* snapshots and **compare them**.  It uses `git diff` to do that.  Note: some commits—*merge* commits in particular—have *more than one parent*, which presents a problem here.  Exercise for the reader: what does `git log` do about this problem?

When `git log` runs `git diff`, to compare a commit's parent's snapshot to the commit's snapshot, this produces a *recipe by which one can change the previous snapshot into the commit's snapshot*.  That's not necessarily what someone actually did!  It just *achieves the same result*.

If the `git diff` that `git log` runs has `--find-renames` enabled, this recipe may include the instruction *rename a file*.  Git produces this, as part of the recipe, under some specific conditions, including:

- The rename has to "work", in some sense, to reduce the amount of changes that would be displayed.
- The detector has to be enabled in the first place.
- The detector has to not be fooled.

Things that can fool the detector include complicated renamings, where `path/to/file1` becomes `other/file3`, `path/to/file2` becomes `new/file2`, `other/file3` becomes `path/to/file2`, and so on.  The "same name for different file contents" stuff gets in the way.  A future Git version may be smarter, and detect these renames.  Or it might not.  The *commits* just hold *snapshots;* it's up to computer programmers to make Git's contents-comparers smarter.  How and when they do that affects when and whether we'll see existing commits in a new way.

Another thing that fools the detector is *limiting the number of paths that `git log` might look at*.  You can run `git log -- path/to/file`, and `git log` will "trim away" other file path-names before running the file-comparing code.  Adding the `--follow` flag tells `git log` to run the rename-detector code differently (it can still be fooled, but because it will run sooner, it is less likely to be followed by this trimming-away of file paths).

What this all boils down to is that the *exact set of `git log` arguments* can make a great deal of difference here.  The rename detector is also enabled by default for some operations, but not for others, and your Git *version* determines in part which operations have rename detection enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

You should rename the file using the `git mv`. if you did using the `git mv` then git would have recognized that you have renamed the file.

```
$ git mv old_filename new_filename
```

The git status would show

```
$ git status
# On branch your-branch
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
#
#     renamed: old_filename -> new_filename
#
```

Comment: Then how come github shows both files correctly? Like github shows A as deleted and B as added/new file even without the mv command

Comment: if the file is renamed using `mv` command, then according to git the old file (A) has been deleted and a new file (B) has been created. Git does not consider the linux mv command as rename.

Comment: Use of `git mv` makes no difference here.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Right click on file name and copy the relative path to file.

2 - In Terminal : git mv file_name.tsx(copied path here) File_name.tsx(Updated name here with full path).

3 - If you are making a case sensitive update then you might have to change it to temporary name first and then run command again with updated name you want.

Git will pickup the files.